# rrdtool graph resolution changes when plotting yesterday

Tags: graph, rrdtool, rrd

I am having problem with graph that plots yesterday. The resolution of Y axis looks like [1 hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGb4T.png). Graph is created with:

`rrdtool graph /ram/temperature/sensors-yesterday.png \
--end 00:00 \
--rigid \
--width 638 --height 337 \
--border 0 \
--font AXIS:13:0 \
--color BACK#363636 \
--color CANVAS#363636 \
--color GRID#999999 \
--color MGRID#B5B5B5 \
--color FONT#CCCCCC \
--x-grid MINUTE:60:HOUR:1:MINUTE:360:0:%R \
--y-grid 1:1 \
DEF:Onetemp=ds_temperature.rrd:One:AVERAGE \`

*(code to shade the sunlight is not included)*

When I plot graph for last 24 hours without `--end 00:00 \`

everything looks normal, resolution is 5 minutes ([-24 hours graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnn6O.png))

Database is created with:

`rrdtool create ds_temperature.rrd  --step 300 \
DS:One:GAUGE:600:-60:60 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:12 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:288 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:168 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:720 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:365`

And sampled with data every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the resolution change is that you do not have data at 5 minute resolution for more than 24h ... revisit your create statement. My suggestion:

```
rrdtool create ds_temperature.rrd  --step 300 \
DS:One:GAUGE:600:-60:60 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2880 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:720 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:365
```

Comment: Many thanks. I am going to try it. I have to study **rrdtool create** at your page.